# What's the recommended way to create and pass a wrapped component to React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I have a bunch of routes, and I want to wrap the component that is rendered for each route in a styled `div`, but I'm trying to make the code DRYer.

How would you refactor this so that I can add `n` routes without repeating the `<div>` each time?

```
<Route
   path="/"
   exact
   component={
     <div className={css(styles.fadeIn)}>
       <Home />
     </div>
    }
   />
<Route
 path="/about"
 exact
 component={
   <div className={css(styles.fadeIn)}>
     <About />
   </div>
  }
 />
```

Comment: Wrap it around the `Route`? The `Route` component doesn't render anything in itself, so it won't get in the way of your style.

Comment: @ChrisR  I think wrapping would not work with this fadeIn style, i'll just move the divs inside the components or wrap with a js controlled fadeIn div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compose the `Route` component pretty much the same as any other react component. You could do the following:

```
const AnimatedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest}) => (
  <div className={css(styles.fadeIn)}>
    <Route component={Component} {...rest} />
  </div>
)

//Somewhere else
<AnimatedRoute component={About} />
```